# How do I change the content shown in the master section of a master detail page using Prism

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I'm migrating our app from MvvmCross as we need to add Intune support and using MVX is preventing this.

The app is essentially an email reader, so currently we are using a MasterDetail page and loading a folder list into master which on phones becomes the flyout and on tablets this appears in the left of the split view.

When you select a folder from this page  we then show a message list - this loads into the detail on phone, but for tablets we use MVX functionality to load this into master, this is also wrapped inside a nav page so you can go back to the folder list. Essentially we have a nav stack inside the master section on tablets and also one in the detail section.

I've checked and played around with the Prism samples, but they don't appear to cover this scenario. The documentation recommends only having fixed content in the master section and this is bound to the master detail view model. This is different to what we have currently, essentially we can control where any page ends up depending on idiom.

I would just like confirmation that it is possible for me to be able to load a page into detail or master depending on the device idiom and any examples would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Generally speaking, yes.  But you would have to write the code to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered this myself by taking a look in the source and there is no support in the Prism navigation service to load a page into master. Everything is overridable, but I feel it would result in lots of changes and issues if I try and introduce this concept.

We'll have to discuss internally if changing the UI flow on tablets is acceptable, if not then Prism is a no go and we'll look at alternatives or write our own navigation service to support it.

Answer (score 0):

The Master property of the MasterDetailPage is a basic Page object so it does not have a navigation stack available but the property itself does have a getter and a setter so you should be able to set the page manually. We use a master page and as a quick test I was able to set it using:

```
((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Master = new SwapMaster();
```

What might be possible that I didn't try is actually set the Master as a NavigationPage. Then you might be able to push onto the Master's navigation stack. Again, I did not try this ATM.

**Update:**
So I did play around quickly with setting the Master to a navigation page and then pushing and popping pages on and off the stack. It did work but the behavior was a little squirrelly but it does show it might be possible.

[image: Set the master to navigation]

Push on the stack:

```
((NavigationPage)Master).Navigation.PushAsync(new SwapMasterPage());
```

Pop the stack:

```
((NavigationPage)((MasterDetailPage)Application.Current.MainPage).Master).Navigation.PopAsync();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've done it that way for years when I've written my own navigation service, my question was specifically asking how to do it in Prism - the question was tagged with Prism, but have added it to the title.